# query doesnt work multi cols update

Tags: php, mysql

hello i am trying to update my database ones user leaves , and i want insert all user data : hare is my script :

```
 $stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET (
        userid,
        username,
        usertype,
        email,
        level,
        exp,
        money,
        ninjarank,
        avatar,
        village,
        clan,
        guild,
        healthpoint,
        chakrapoint,
        ninjutsu,
        taijutsu,
        genjutsu,
        senjutsu,
        talent,
        chakra,
        health,
        chakracontrol
        ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE userid= ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("isisiiisssssiiiiiiiiiii",
                     $userid,
                     $username,
                     $usertype,
                     $email,
                     $level,
                     $exp,
                     $money,
                     $ninjarank,
                     $avatar,
                     $village,
                     $clan,
                     $guild,
                     $healthpoint,
                     $chakrapoint,
                     $ninjutsu,
                     $taijutsu,
                     $genjutsu,
                     $senjutsu,
                     $talent,
                     $chakra,
                     $health,
                     $chakracontrol,
                     $userid
                         );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $connect->close();
```

but this query doesnt work get no result at all , i am set one of the valued +1000 just to make sure that query runs successfully but the value in database are the same please help with this query

Comment: Why you are using UPDATE and not INSERT? This seems to be insert query.

Comment: @chandresh_cool you can not use the where clause with insert

Comment: Yes my point was why is he using wrong clause, he should use where clause and update statement.

Comment: @PedroLobito 22 values but there is 23th value witch is user= ? and user so i am updating where user id = user id and user id = session userid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an `INSERT` and not `UPDATE` syntax, use this format:

```
UPDATE users u
SET u.username = ?,
    u.OtherColumn = ?,
    ......
WHERE u.user_id = ?
```

Or, if you actually want to insert, then replace `UPDATE` with `INSERT` and delete the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: could you check my query and jquery cuz its seems one of them are not working https://jsfiddle.net/r4gbvjfq/

Comment: You should open a new question, with all the information needed mate , I have little understanding about `PHP` . In general, try removing the `userid` from the update, you should not update the key of the table.